# PhoneGap plugin install not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have PhoneGap 3.x installed, and have been using the command line API to build out my android app.

I need access to some hardware features like contacts, so I used the API to install the plugin.  However, when I list the installed plugins, none are found, and the contacts object on navigator is not defined.

Here is the command line commands:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 minutes 3 seconds
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app

phonegap plugin list
[phonegap] no plugins installed

phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
[phonegap] adding the plugin: org.apache.cordova.contacts
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin

phonegap plugin list
[phonegap] no plugins installed
```

I tried deleting both the plugins folder content, and re-creating my Android platform, then tried to re-add the plugins, but no luck.

The plugin is in the plugins folder with what looks like the correct content, there is an android.xml file in the plugins folder, but for some reason PG doesn't see that the plugin is installed.

I am on Windows 7, phonegap ver 3.5.0-0.20.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here on Mac OS, phonegap v3.5.0-0.20.4

The problem comes from an error in the file *lib/phonegap/local.plugin.list.js* where the return list of plugins is not correct.

```
LocalPluginListCommand.prototype.listPlugins = function(plugins, callback) {
var self = this,
    e = null;

// error is not supported by cordova, but this is for the future
if (plugins instanceof Error) {
    e = plugins;
    plugins = [];
    self.phonegap.emit('error', e);
} else if (typeof plugins === 'string') {
    // identify the "no plugins" response to phonegapify the output
    if (plugins.indexOf('No plugins added') > -1) {
        plugins = [];
        self.phonegap.emit('log', 'no plugins installed');
    }
    else {
        // list plugins
        self.phonegap.emit('log', plugins);
    }
}
callback(e, plugins);
```

};

Here is the official correction of the wrong file :
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/commit/d8d54ece21300dad63015779b6c5c629510c17d6

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Good start. It's not clear whether you're posting the erroneous code or the correction though.

Comment: I did notice that the plugins were there, it was just the list that was broken, thanks for the detailed answer